# Is there a good way to merge data based on a drop down menu in R?

Tags: shiny

I have been trying to merge data with another data set based on input from a drop down. I have just started learning R and have run into some problems and want to know if there is a better way of going about this.

I am getting an error that it cannot coerce class c(ReactiveExpr, reactive) to a data frame.

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

server <- function(input, output){
    
    annotation1 <- read.xlsx("input1.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)
    
    annotation2 <- read.xlsx("input2.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)
    
    data_input <- eventReactive(input$userfile, {
        df <- read.xlsx(input$userfile$datapath, sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)
    })
    
    output$data_input <- renderTable(data_input())
    output$annotation <- renderTable(annotation)
    
    data_species <-  c("Set1", "Set2")
    
    # Drop-down selection box for which data set
    output$choose_species <- renderUI ({
        selectInput("species", "Species", as.list(data_species))
    })
    
    output$mergeddata <- renderTable({
        if(input$species == "Set1"){
            eventReactive("Set1",({left_join(data_input(), annotation1, by = c("Column1" = "Column1"))}))
        }
        
        else if(input$species == "Set2"){
            eventReactive("Set2",({left_join(data_input(), annotation2, by = c("Column1" = "Column1"))}))
        }
        
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel(
        div("Test")
    ),
    

    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("userfile", "Input File", multiple =FALSE,
                      buttonLabel = "Browse Files", placeholder = "Select File"),
            
            uiOutput("choose_species"),
            
            uiOutput("choose_annotations"),
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("mergeddata"),
            br()
        ),
    
),

)


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you approach seems ok. The error you get is from the line

```
eventReactive("Set1",({left_join(data_input(), annotation1, by = c("Column1" = "Column1"))}))
```

An `eventReactive` returns an (unevaluated) reactive expression which you try to render as data.frame with `renderTable`. To circumvent this, you could use:

```
eventReactive("Set1",({left_join(data_input(), annotation1, by = c("Column1" = "Column1"))}))()
```

However, here you don't need `eventReactive`, because your reactivity comes from `input$species` (you want to change the table output based on this input). Therefore, you can just use:

```
output$mergeddata <- renderTable({
  
  if(input$species == "Set1"){
    merge_data <- annotation1
  } else {
    merge_data <- annotation2
  }
  
  left_join(data_input(), merge_data, by = c("Column1"))
  
})
```